# Powershell - Export csv for program name, version, installdate

Tags: powershell, csv

im trying to run a command against a list of computers to find out information on the programs on the computers. then i would like to export that information on a Csv in the following format:

Computer name, McAfee Agent, version, Installdate

i wanted to get the list of these computers and the programs version numbers and installdate.

this command works, but not for exporting:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_product -ComputerName SYSTEMName01 | Where name -Match "McAfee Agent" | Select Name, Version, Installdate
```

I tried using the following code here, but this isn't working because it populates the information in Powershell then gives me a:

- "RPC server is unavailable" red text.
- and the Exported CSV document only gives me one populated row of the Name of the program and its version # and install date. but it doesn't populate the computer name it looked into and it doesn't list the other computers in the .txt document.

```
$computers = Get-content -Path "C:\nice\List-of-systems.txt"
Get-WmiObject win32_product -ComputerName $computers | Where name -Match "McAfee Agent" | Select Name, Version, Installdate |
Export-Csv -Path "C:\nice\computers-mcafee-status.csv"
```

Comment: What is _doesn't work_ ? What does your `C:\nice\List-of-systems.txt` look like?

Comment: it looks like list one right under the other with system names on the network that i can ping. no IP addresses

or did you want an image reference?

Comment: You're not exporting the ComputerName, and you need to `-Append` to the file.

Comment: Currently your script will stop at the first error - if you want it to check all computers you need to write it to account for any errors in connecting.

Comment: This is a place where you might be better off with a `foreach ($system in $computers) {Get-WMIObject ... -ErrorAction Ignore}` to process the list of computers - doing so will allow you to get all the computers that are accessible, while skipping those that are unable to respond to the WMI call.

Comment: (The `-ErrorAction Ignore` is to prevent it from aborting as soon as it hits a computer that's not able to respond. You might want to look up [`about_CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're gonna go through the trouble of just querying single information, might as well query the system info a long with it.

```
<#
SYNTAX
    Get-SystemInfo [[-ComputerName] <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

EXAMPLE
    Get-SystemInfo -ComputerName SystemOne, SystemTwo
    'SystemOne', 'SystemTwo' | Get-SystemInfo
    Get-content -Path "C:\nice\List-of-systems.txt" | Get-SystemInfo
    Get-content -Path "C:\nice\List-of-systems.txt" | Get-SystemInfo | Export-CSV C:\List-Of-Systems.csv -NoTypeInformation
#>
Function Get-SystemInfo{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
               ValueFromPipeLine=$True,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
               HelpMessage='Enter Computer Name')]
               [Alias('CN','Name')]
               [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME)
Process{
    try{
        #$ExportPath = "C:\nice\computers-mcafee-status.csv"
        #if(-Not(Test-Path -Path '$ExportPath')){
            #New-Item '$ExportPath' -ItemType File }           
            foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
                $CIMSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
                #$OS        = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CIMSession -Namespace Root/CIMv2 -ClassName WIN32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $CS         = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CIMSession -Namespace Root/CIMv2 -ClassName WIN32_ComputerSystem -Property Model,Manufacturer,Username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $BS         = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CIMSession -Namespace Root/CIMv2 -ClassName WIN32_BIOS -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $MAC        = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CIMSession -Namespace Root/CIMv2 -ClassName WIN32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object -Property Description -Like "*Ethernet*" 
                $MA         = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CIMSession -Namespace Root/CIMv2 -ClassName WIN32_Product | Where-Object Name -Match "McAfee Agent" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    

                    [PSCustomobject] @{
                        "Computer Name"         = $Computer
                        "Status"                = "Online"
                        "Manufacturer"          = if($CS.Manufacturer){$CS.Manufacturer}Else{"Unable to get Manufacturer"}
                        "Model"                 = if($CS.Model){$CS.Model}Else{"Unable to get Model"}
                        "User Logged in"        = if($cs.UserName){$cs.UserName}Else{"No user logged in"}
                        "Serial Number"         = if($BS.SerialNumber){$BS.SerialNumber}Else{"Unable to get Serial #"}
                        "MAC Address"           = if($MAC.MACAddress){$MAC.MACAddress}Else{"Unable to get MAC Address"}
                        "McAfee InstallDate"    = if($MA.InstallDate){$MA.InstallDate}Else{"Unable to get InstallDate"}
                        "McAfee Version"        = if($Ma.Version){$MA.Version}Else{"Unable to get Version"}

                        } #| Export-Csv -Path '$ExportPath' -Append -NoTypeInformation
                    }
                } Catch [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException] {
                     [PSCustomobject] @{
                        "Computer Name"      = $Computer
                        "Status"             = "Offline"
                        "Manufacturer"       = $null
                        "Model"              = $null
                        "User Logged in"     = $null
                        "Serial Number"      = $null
                        "MAC Address"        = $null
                        "McAfee InstallDate" = $null
                        "McAfee Version"     = $null 
                    } #| Export-Csv -Path '$ExportPath' -Append -NoTypeInformation
                } Finally {
                    if($CIMSession){
                      Get-CimSession | Remove-CimSession
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue with what you're trying to do is, you're not including the computername to be exported along with the other information. You also need to `-Append` to the file. The errors you receive mean that you just couldn't connect to the remote machine.

Comment: this is awesome! ive learned alot from this thank you so much!

Comment: Hopefully it gets you what you need. Have a good weekend!